Fatal error 403 Github when make push on cpanel terminal
I am working on a big repo with another repos inside on cpanel and I would like to push my changes to github on an specific repo. I am inside an organization, with write privileges and every time I try to push I get remote: write access to repository not granted. Fatal: unable to access 'my repo' the requested url returned fatal error 403.
In theory I have all the permissions, writing, I am one of the owners and I dont know what else to do
I tried to change permissions, change the remote url, I am using github token. I dont know exactly what else to do.
